# Query string in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, session, query-string

After I [remove index.php](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/urls.html), I enable query string in codeigniter . But I have some trouble with redirect link. Detail , I have login form (login/index) and when login success redirect to "welcome/index" and save email in session .

> But when login success only load view of "welcome/index" and wrong link , now link is :
>   "?login/index" And session don't save . Please help me .

Here's my code

Login.php (Controller)

```
if($this->input->post('email') != '' && $this->input->post('password') != ''){
        if ($this->user->CheckLogin($this->input->post('email'),$this->input->post('password')) == true)
        {
            $this->load->library('session');
            $this->session->set_flashdata('email', $this->input->post('email'));
            redirect('welcome/index', 'refresh');
        }
        else
        {
            $data['error_message'] = '* Email or Password is incorrect';
            $this->load->view('login',$data);
        }
    }else{
            $this->load->view('login',$data);
    }
```

Welcome.php (Controller)

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

public function index()
    {
         $this->load->model('user');
         $this->load->helper('url');
         $this->load->library('session');

         $data['email'] = $this->session->flashdata('email');
         $this->load->view('welcome_message',$data);
    }
}
```

welcome_message.php (View)

```
<?php 
    // Cant print email
    echo $email; 
?>
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: On your config.php have you made `$config['uri_protocol'] = 'QUERY_STRING';`

Comment: Thanks . It's working but all my link have "?" character . Example : ?welcome/index , ?login/index . Why's that  :(

Comment: Could be due to your htaccess file in main directory if have any.

Comment: I just update .htaccess file you can check for me . Thanks :)

Comment: Did you by any chance `$config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;` or is it set to TRUE

Comment: Of course i set it TRUE :)

Comment: Just testing try with FALSE;

Comment: I think the ? should only show up once near start of just after index.php area and then rest use & `$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-#=&?';`

Comment: Sorry but it's not working :(

Comment: @wolfgang1983 Can you help me :(

Comment: I cannot think of any thing else atm but i know for query string's to work you need ?

Comment: @wolfgang1983 $config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-#=&?';  my link have "?" character :(

Answer (score 0):

If you enable **Query Strings** then change the redirect like this

> `redirect('c=welcome &m=index', 'refresh');`

Additionally it may required to write `index.php?` or only `?` before `c`

Or if change configuation in **config.php** then you need change the `c and m`
like

> $config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;
>       $config['controller_trigger'] = 'c';
>       $config['function_trigger'] = 'm';

for more info http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html#enabling-query-strings

Comment: But I use GET query without **enable Query Strings** like this `htttp://example.com/controller/method/12?filter=no & name=someone`